# Reading in an unknown number of elements from a file to an array?

Tags: java

As the title states, I'm trying to read an unknown # of elements from a file into an array. What's the most simple (professor wants us to avoid using things she hasnt taught) yet effective way of going about this?

I've thought about reading and counting the elements in the file one by one, then create the array after I know what size to make it, then actually store the elements in there. But that seems a little inefficient. Is there a better way?

Comment: You situation is exactly what `ArrayList` is for. Just convert it into the array after you finished reading (if for some reason you don't like list).

Comment: _professor wants us to avoid using things she hasn't taught_ Has the professor told you about `java.util.ArrayList` class?

Answer (score 3):

There are only two ways to do this: the way you suggested (count, then read), and making an array and hoping it's good enough, then resize if it's not (which is the easier of the two, as `ArrayList` does that automatically for you).

Which is better depends on whether you're more limited by time or memory (as typically reading the file twice will be slower than reallocating an array even multiple times).

EDIT: There is a third way, which is only available if each record in the file has a fixed width, and the file is not compressed (or encoded in any other way that would mess with the content layout): get the size of the file, divide by record size, and that's exactly how many records you have to allocate for. Unfortunately, life is not always that easy. :)

Answer (score 0):

As you have not mentioned that your professor has taught `ArrayList` or not so, in that case I would go for `ArrayList` for sure. The sole purpose f `ArrayList` is to deal with this kind of situations. Features like **Dynamic Memory** gives `ArrayList` some advantages over array.

You can count first and then create array accordingly. But this will be slow and why reinvent the wheel?

So, your approach should be to use `ArrayList` read the element and just use `ArrayList.add()`...